# Universal Sentence Encoder TypeError prunded(text) expected Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I have downloaded universal sentence encoder 2 to a computer without internet access and unpacked to a destination folder: 'data.'

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

USE_embedder = hub.load(r'data/')
```

If I then run `USE_embedder(['test'])` as I normally would, I get the error: `TypeError: 'Autotrackable' object is not callable.` But following the tensorflow docs, I would think that I could run:

```
USE_embedder.signatures['default'](['test'])
```

But I get the TypeError:

```
TypeError: pruned(text: expected argument #0(zero-based to be a Tensor; got list(['test'])
```

When I can run this from a networked computer, loading from https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2 rather than the extracted download, I can run something like this just fine. How can I enable the model to embed text as is normally show in the docs (e.g., `USE_embedder(['text'])` returns a vector).

Using: Python 3.6.7, Tensorflow 2.4.1, Tensorflow_hub 0.11.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work when you convert your list to a tensor:

```
USE_embedder.signatures['default'](tf.constant(['test']))
```

(tested with TF 2.4.1, tensorflow_hub 0.11.0)